# How to insert latex dot without new line

Tags: latex

Im trying to add a dot like `•` for a dot product but it always ends up acting like a bullet point creating a new line. I've tried `\cdot` and `\bullet`. I think its being treated as a bullet because I'm doing it inside an itemized list. Is there a way to make it just as a dot?

Comment: This would be a good question to ask at the [LaTeX Stack Exchange site](http://tex.stackexchange.com) (now in beta). Also, it would really help to have a minimal but complete example of LaTeX source code that displays your problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
$\bullet$
```

Comment: nope and that worked so thank you! What exactly do the $ signs do?

Comment: `$` brackets in-line math mode.

Answer (score 7):

Try `\cdot` in math mode. It is a good way to indicate multiplication:
[image]

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  Here is a product: $a \cdot b$.
  \end{document}
```

Note that the dollar symbol represents the math mode.

Answer (score 5):

just had the same problem...

Math mode `$...$` is not essential for this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Here's an example with $\bullet$ math mode
\newline
And here one in \textbullet text only
\newline
Although you may want to give the last \textbullet \ more spacing
\end{document}
```

giving:

[image]